# Evaluation of the configuration body of a custom pipeline step implementation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

For a custom Jenkins pipeline step I have some pipeline using this step like:

```
library 'infrastructure'

infrastructurePipeline {
    project ='jenkins'
    artifact = ['master', 'backup']

    dockerRegistry = [
            credentialsId: 'dockerRegistryDeployer',
            url : "http://${env.DOCKER_REGISTRY}"
    ]
}
```

However, in this context the variable `env` doesn't seem to be bound hence the expression can't be evaluated.

I can replace `env` by `System.getenv()` and it will work. But this comes with a side-effect that I would rather avoid. I have to approve the usage of `System.getenv()` which is warned to be a security vulnerabulity.

The custom step implements configuration evaluation as recommended in https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl.

The most relevant code for the step is in `vars/infrastructurePipeline.groovy`

```
def call(Closure body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    def label=config.label ?: 'docker'

    String tag = env.BUILD_NUMBER
    String deliveryTag=null

    String project = config.project
    def artifact = config.artifact
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the body of your `infrastructurePipeline` method and your `infrastructure` library? It would help to understand how you are writing your function.

`System.getenv()` will get attempt to get the environment of the Jenkins master running the script which is why you get the script security approval issue. You probably don't want that.

Comment: Added the requested code to the question.